# Free/malloc functions in windows kernel

Tags: windows, function, kernel, malloc, free

Where i can find `free` and `malloc` functions in kernel? I do include `stdlib.h` but `free` and `malloc` functions are not in `stdlib.h`. Where i can find these functions?

Thanks!

Comment: @cnicutar Sorry, Windows kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [ExAllocatePoolWithTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There's some discussion at [OSR](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=59047), which is a good resource if you're doing windows kernel programming.

Install the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx)/DDK for all the development files and docs on your local host.